# Difference between basis path testing and full path testing?

Tags: testing, path, nodes, context-free-grammar

Looking at them, they both seem like the exact same thing: finding all the possible paths in a CFG. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: ["Basis path testing guarantees complete branch coverage (all CFG edges), but achieves that without covering all possible CFG paths—the latter is usually too costly."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_path_testing). Note, full path testing covers all possible CFG paths.

Comment: Oh, guess I missed that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is Path Testing?

Path testing is a structural testing method that involves using the source code of a program in order to find every possible executable path. It helps to determine all faults lying within a piece of code. This method is designed to execute all or selected path through a computer program.

Any software program includes, multiple entry and exit points. Testing each of these points is a challenging as well as time consuming. In order to reduce the redundant tests and to achieve maximum test coverage, basis path testing is used.

What is Basis Path Testing?

The basis path testing is same, but it is based on a white box testing method, that defines test cases based on the flows or logical path that can be taken through the program. Basis path testing involves execution of all possible blocks in a program and achieves maximum path coverage with least number of test cases. It is a hybrid of branch testing and path testing methods.

The objective behind basis path testing is that it defines the number of independent paths, thus the number of test cases needed can be defined explicitly (maximizes the coverage of each test case).